# Como verificar integridade de videos .mp4?

Tags: windows, vídeo

Tenho em mãos cerca de 10.000 videos em formato .mp4, porém alguns deles estão corrompidos. Tais arquivos estão corrompidos da seguinte maneira: os videos deveriam ter uma certa duração de tempo, entretanto, quando são reproduzidos, tais videos são fechados automaticamente antes do tempo. Creio que esse erro é proveniente de um download mal sucedido.

Gostaria de saber algum programa/método que faça a analise de todos esses videos, e me aponte quais estão corrompidos.
Não há necessidade de reparar os videos corrompidos, apenas apontar quais estão com erro.

OBS: estou usando Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Thiago Benine**, veja passo a passo como EU faria (considerando que os arquivos de video estão em uma pasta só em `C:\videos` e que os nomes dos arquivos estão sem espaço e sem acento (utilize o [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) se precisar padronizar os nomes dos arquivos de uma só vez):

1. Crie uma lista num documento texto com TODOS os nomes dos arquivos de video:

   1. Abra o MS-DOS, navegue até a pasta com os vídeos (`cd C:\videos` por exemplo)
   2. Ainda no MS-DOS, exporte o nome dos arquivos .mp4 usando:

      - `dir *.mp4 /b >>arquivos_de_video.txt`
2. Com os nomes dos arquivos de video em `C:\videos\arquivos_de_video.txt`, baixe o [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) para Windows.
3. Abra o arquivo `C:\videos\arquivos_de_video.txt`com um bom editor de textos (recomendo o [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3), pois com ele, é possível clicar com o botão do MEIO do mouse e arrastar selecionando MÚLTIPLAS linhas) e insira a linha de comando do `FFMPEG` para verificar CADA arquivo de vídeo:

   - `ffmpeg.exe -v error -i video.mp4 -f null - >video.txt 2>&1`
4. Renomeie `C:\videos\arquivos_de_video.txt` para `C:\videos\verifica_videos.bat` (extensão `.bat`)
5. Execute via `MS-DOS` seu novo recém arquivo .bat: `C:\videos\verifica_videos.bat`

Exemplo de como ficaria o **`C:\videos\verifica_videos.bat`**:

```
ffmpeg.exe -v error -i video1.mp4 -f null - >video1_erro.txt 2>&1
ffmpeg.exe -v error -i video2.mp4 -f null - >video2_erro.txt 2>&1
ffmpeg.exe -v error -i video3.mp4 -f null - >video3_erro.txt 2>&1
(...)
```

Este é obviamente o exemplo mais simples que poderia se dar. O ideal seria programar (C# ou outra linguagem) uma saída mais dinâmica e rápida.

Não esqueça de inserir corretamente o caminho do `ffmpeg.exe` baixado no passo `2)`.

Não esqueça de alterar também o nome do arquivo de erro `video.txt` para o `nome_do_video_erro.txt` assim, os arquivos os erros serão exibidos na mesma ordem no seu Windows Explorer.

Infelizmente o tempo de verificação (com ou sem FFMPEG) é praticamente o mesmo de conversão de um vídeo, portanto, 10.000 vídeos pode demorar bastante.

**RESUMO**

1. Criar uma lista dos videos num documento de texto.
2. Editar o arquivo de texto com os nomes dos videos com um bom editor de textos (Sublime, por exemplo) e inserir a linha de comando de verificação do FFMPEG em cada uma das linhas do arquivo de texto.
3. Renomear a lista de arquivos de video para a extensão .bat
4. Executar o recém arquivo .bat via MS-DOS

Comment: Boa noite Felipe, notei que você tem colaborado bastante e sempre com ótimas resposta, porém note que antes de responder algumas perguntas seria legal dar uma olhada no que faz parte do escopo do site http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . Fazer um comentário pode ajudar, mas formular uma resposta pode incentivar a ter muitas perguntas que não fazem parte do escopo do site e quando o autor da pergunta tiver sua questão vai se sentir frustado, devido antes ele conseguir resposta para algo offtopic e depois não conseguir mais.

Comment: Felipe, você poderia me dar um exemplo de como ficaria o .txt após concluir a etapa 3?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, boa noite. Entendi bem o escopo de [help/on-topic](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Mas não acha que sua mensagem poderia ser destinada ao `@Thiago Benine`, que formulou a pergunta? De qualquer maneira, agora sei exatamente o escopo das questões, obrigado.

Comment: @Thiago Benine, o exemplo seria exatamente o que está após a etapa 5 em `Exemplo de como ficaria o C:\videos\verifica_videos.bat`.

Comment: @FelipeDouradinho Quando a pergunta é off-topic existe um sistema que "fecha" ou "suspende" a pergunta e aparece uma mensagem no rodapé. O comentário foi destinado a ti, pois no momento que você respondeu indiretamente você está incentivando perguntas off-topic. Não há mal algum em responder, mas recomendo que ou evite ou "Sinalize" as perguntas off-topic, mesmo que você tenha ou não respondido.

Comment: @FelipeDouradinho como farei para inserir o codigo do ffmpeg da etapa 3, para verificar 10.000 videos? Terei que escrever manualmente?

Comment: Dúvida sanada pelo @FelipeDouradinho